# Unknown class style $000B (0x000B)

Tags: winapi

GetClassInfo function returns unknown class style for "COMBOBOX" and "BUTTON" class names. The same occurs to GetClassInfoEx.

Having the code (in Pascal):

```
const
  CS_GLOBALCLASS = $4000;
  CS_PARENTDC    = $0080;
  CS_DBLCLKS     = $0008;
```

After calling GetClassInfo (or GetClassInfoEx):

1. For className = "STATIC" or "EDIT", I get Style = `$4088`
2. For className = "COMBOBOX" or "BUTTON", I get Style = `$408B`

This is what I understand from the values returned:

```
$4088 = (CS_GLOBALCLASS or CS_PARENTDC or CS_DBLCLKS);
$408B = (CS_GLOBALCLASS or CS_PARENTDC or $000B);
```

What class type is `$000B`?
Is it undocumented?

NOTE: I'm running Windows 7 32-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0x0B` is these flags `OR`'ed together:

`0x8 | 0x2 | 0x1` = `CS_DBLCLKS | CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW`